# Ruby How do I get a 2d array from HTML form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a tickets booking system. 
I have a 2d array stored the seat and the status

```
@movie1 = [["A1", 0], ["A2", 0], ["A3", 1],["A4", 1], ["A5", 1], ["A6", 1], ["A7", 1], ["A8", 1], ["A9", 0], ["A10", 1]]
```

And this is the view

```
<form action= "seat/test4" method="get">

    <table>
     <% for i in 0..9 do %>
      <% if i == 0 then %>
      <tr>
      <% end %>

     <% if @movie1[i][1] == 1 then %>
       <td bgcolor="red">
         <%= @movie1[i][0] %>
         <input type = button value = "X"
       </td>         
     <%  else  %>
        <td bgcolor="green">
          <%= @movie1[i][0] %>
          <input type="checkbox" id= <%= @movie1[i][0] %> name = <%= @movie1[i][0] %> > 
        </td>
     <% end %>

        <% if i == 9 then %>
     </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

    </table>

   <input type="submit" value="Purchase">
</form>
```

How can I get the checkbox value and change the `@movie1[i][1] = 1` ?

Comment: Please post the code here, not as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change `@movie1`. `@movie1` is a ruby variable it renders when page loads and it cannot be changed after that. if you really want to change the variable without page reload you can do it via `Ajax call` Rails itself has feature to accomplish that.

To know more refer this link:

[Working with javascript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Also Refer about rails partial

[Rails Partial](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

This is used to create subtemplates, is usefull for dynamic cases like this.

As a Suggestion you can also implement the view as follows

```
 <form action= "seat/test4" method="get">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <% @movie1.each do |m| %>
      <% if m[1] == 1 %>
        <td bgcolor="red">
        <%= m[0] %>
        <input type = button value = "X" />
      </td>         
      <%  else  %>
       <td bgcolor="green">
        <%= m[0] %>
        <input type="checkbox" id= <%= m[0] %> value="<%= m[0] %>" name = <%= m[0] %> /> 
      </td>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="Purchase">
 </form>
```

Also add value attribute to checkbox tag